# Automated installation of SSL certificates to Android devices

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate

We are creating an "extranet" application that will use client/server SSL certificates to enhance security.  Is it possible to create an installer that would be run by a user on their Android device that would install a client SSL certificate issued to them by us?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be mostly resolved in the next release of the Android OS.

http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=11231#c107